# Injecting Map properties from yaml file in JEE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, yaml, cdi

I recently started to work with JEE (with CDI and Payara), and I'm trying to understand if I can inject properties from yaml file that are written as map structure.

In Spring it was pretty easy, just using *@Value* on field of a type Map, or *@ConfigurationProperties* on a class, and that is it.

Is something like that possible in JEE app?

Comment: Something like this: https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html?

Comment: or searching for 'cdi configuration yaml' in a searchengine? Or if you by know know the existence of deltaspike (great for other things too) then combine that in a search: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cdi+deltaspike+config+yaml and find https://github.com/chattersley/deltaspike-config-advanced So making search engines your friend helps (initial searching without yaml to broaden the base search for cdi and config(uration) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not out of the box with a Java EE application.

To provide a `Map` of any kind for injection elsewhere, you will need to arrange for something to make it.

To arrange for something to make a `Map` that can be injected somewhere (or any other object), you can use a variety of CDI tools, of which [`@Produces`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/apidocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html) is probably the best choice.  There are other choices.  You might be interested in [a CDI tutorial I wrote for relative newcomers](https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2019/05/18/a-cdi-primer-part-0/).

Finally, you may wish to look at [MicroProfile Config](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config), which will allow for similar but not quite exactly the same sort of functionality.